# Multiple devices with I2C on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I'm attempting to read data from the VL53L1X-SATEL and the TSL2561 Luminosity Sensor at the same time using I2C on the Raspberry Pi 3 B+. When just the vl53l1x is connected I get the following from i2cdetect -y 1:

```
pi@BIKE_SENSOR_SYSTEM:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1

    00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 29 -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

    70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

With just the tsl2561 connected I get:

```
pi@BIKE_SENSOR_SYSTEM:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1

00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 39 -- -- -- -- -- -- 

40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

This is as expected.

From what I've read online, in order for them to work together the two devices should be connected in parallel to the corresponding pins on the pi. However, when I do this I get:

```
pi@BIKE_SENSOR_SYSTEM:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1

00:          -- -- 05 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

10: -- -- -- 13 -- -- -- -- -- -- 1a -- -- -- 1e -- 

20: 20 -- -- -- -- -- 26 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 2f 

30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 39 -- -- 3c -- -- -- 

40: -- -- -- -- -- 45 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

60: 60 -- 62 -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- 6f 

70: -- -- -- 73 -- 75 -- --
```

This changes each time I run i2cdetect -y 1 with only the 39 remaining constant. What do I have to change for i2cdetect to display only the 29 and 39?

Here is how I am connecting the pins:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: You have both devices connected to the same `SDA`, `SCL` and `GND`?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Mmm... you need someone cleverer than me then, but don't worry, there are plenty about. Maybe try on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok I'll have a look thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related. Best to try the [Raspberry Pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Have you got a schematic of wiring? Have you got access to oscilloscope/logic probe?

Comment: I've added a link to the wiring schematic. I do have access to an oscilloscope.

Comment: You should really probe the signals. It might be distorted with too strong pullups (additional resistors on each board), or increased capacitance of the lines. That might explain why each single device is working, while failing when connected both. You can also try to lower i2c clock speed and see if it helps a little.